# Generating function for sum of i.i.d. random variables

Tags: probability, generating-functions

This question is related to probelm 10.(f) of the book Generatingfunctionology (available from the author here: [https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Ewilf/DownldGF.html)), but generic enough to be asked independently (I believe).

The question asks:

*A loaded die has probabilities $.1, .2, .1, .2, .2, .2$ of turning up with,
respectively, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6 spots showing. The die is then thrown
100 times, and we want to calculate the probability $p^∗$ that the total
number of spots on all 100 throws is $\leq 300$. Identify $p^∗$ as the coefficient
of $x^{300}$ in the power series expansion of a certain function. Say exactly
what the function is (you are not being asked to calculate $p^∗$).*

First, I defined $G(x) = \sum_{i=1}^6 p_i x^i$, with $p_i$ the probability of sampling $i$ spots.
And from the previous exercise (10.c) I already know that $[x^n]G(x)^{100}$ is the probability that the sum of all dice throws equals $n$. Then, I want to find $F(x)$ as a power series with coeficients representing the probability of the spots summing $\leq n$. Which I try to do as follows (let $X$ be the R.V. of the loaded die):
$$ f(n) = \Pr\left[\sum_{i=1}^{100} X \leq n\right] = \sum_{j=1}^n \Pr\left[\sum_{i=1}^{100} X = n\right] = \sum_{j=1}^n [x^j]G(x)^{100} $$
Now, I believe my function $F(y)$ should be
$$F(y) = \sum_{n} f(n) y^n = \sum_{n}\left(\sum_{j=1}^n [x^j]G(x)^{100}\right) y^n $$
and $[y^{300}]F(y)$ should give the probability of the sum of the $100$ dice are $\leq 300$.

Still, in the book, the solution states that I should arrive at $[x^n]\frac{G(x)^{100}}{1-x}$, which I can only compute by taking the $f(n)$ out of the summation, as
$$F(y) = \sum_{n} f(n) y^n = f(n) \sum_{n}  y^n = \frac{f(n)}{1-y}.$$
But I don't understand how can this be, as $f(n)$ depends on the variable of the summation (I'm summing multiple $f(n)$, each representing the probaility of getting exactly $n$ spots, from $1$ up to $n$ go get all possibilities $\leq n$).
I appreciate anyone that could provide some clarification to where my reasoning fails.

Comment: You should check what happens when you multiply two generating functions, what you will see is that one has a convolution of the old coefficients into the new generating function. When multiplying specifically with $\frac{1}{1-x}$, you sum of the first few terms. Sorry if unclear, I only have my phone for the moment.

Comment: You are looking to find the generating function of the sum, not a number.  You should think in terms of $f(y)$ (a polynomial in y) rather than $f(n)$ (a number).  The book explains this in Rule 5 of Chapter 2, assuming we are looking at the same edition of *generatingfunctionology*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We already know that the generating $G(x)^{100}$ represents the situation after $100$ rolls of the loaded die. Let's assume this generating function has the following expansion
\begin{align*}
G(x)^{100}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kx^k\tag{1}
\end{align*}
where $a_k$ represents the probability of getting $k$ points after $100$ rolls.

> We are looking for a generating function $H(x)$ with
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[x^{300}]H(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{300}a_k}
> \end{align*}

A useful aspect is to recall that multiplication of a generating function $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kx^k$ with $\frac{1}{1-x}$ adds up the coefficients $a_k$. We have according to (1) using the *[geometric series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)*
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\frac{1}{1-x}G(x)^{100}}&=\left(\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}x^j\right)\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kx^k\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{{k+j=n}\atop{k,j\geq 0}}a_k\right)x^n\tag{2.1}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^na_k\right)x^n}\tag{2.2}
\end{align*}

> We conclude a wanted generating function is $\frac{1}{1-x}G(x)^{100}$ and the solution is according to (2.2):
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[x^{300}]\frac{1}{1-x}G(x)^{100}=\sum_{k=0}^{300}a_k}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (2.1) we multiply out using the *[Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product)*
- In (2.2) we eliminate $j$ by respecting $j=n-k$.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Could you just clarify how to go from $\sum_{k+j=n\\ k,j\geq 0} a_k$ to $\sum_{k=0}^n a_k$?

Comment: @glv: You're welcome. I've added a comment. Note in general we have $\sum_{{k+j=n}\atop{j,k\geq 0}}a_kb_j=\sum_{k=0}^na_kb_{n-k}$. Here we have $b_{n-k}=1$.

Comment: Thanks! I think all is now clear to me!

Comment: @glv: You're welcome. Good to see the answer is helpful. :-)